# Is there an equivalent to a spreadsheet's "freeze pane"?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I have an org file containing something like this:

```
|id   | foo         | bar       | ...
|-----+-------------+-----------| ...
|1    | foo1        | bar1      | ...
|2    | foo2        | bar2      | ...
|.    | .           | .         | .
|.    | .           | .         | .
|.    | .           | .         | .
```

I would like to split the window such that the id is always visible and/or the header is always visible, whichever line/column the cursor is set (that's very different from C-2 or C-3).

I'm aware that you can set a column width with `<n>`, which is a good substitute for splitting vertically, but to keep the headers visible?

Comment: Maybe there's something more convenient, but at least you could open a second window onto the same buffer, vertically above your current window, and keep the headers visible there.

Comment: It won't work if you scroll to the right.